# create User Defined Type with CHECK

Tags: sybase, sybase-ase-15.7

In PostgreSQL one can create a User Defined Type with an implicit CHECK by doing the following:

```
CREATE DOMAIN OrdinalT AS INTEGER CHECK (value >= 0);
```

In Sybase ASE 15.7 I've figured that the following is almost equivalent (except for the CHECK):

```
sp_addtype OrdinalT, "INTEGER";
```

How do I make a CHECK part of the user-defined type definition in Sybase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot make a check condition a part of the type definition syntactically, but you can [create a rule](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36272.1550/html/commands/X43186.htm):

```
CREATE RULE OrdinalTRule AS @value >= 0
```

and [bind it](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36273.1550/html/sprocs/X38718.htm) to the data type:

```
sp_bindrule OrdinalTRule, OrdinalT
```

In order to modify the rule later, you will have to drop and recreate it. Before being dropped, the rule must be [unbound](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36273.1550/html/sprocs/X37191.htm):

```
sp_unbindrule OrdinalT
```

Note that the argument in the last statement is not the rule itself but the type to which the rule is bound.